# Can I drink myself stupid?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

One of the notable 'features' of *Fallout:New Vegas* was the return to the series of 'Low Int Dialog' -  that is to say, special dialog options in conversations that reflected the fact that you had rolled a Very Stupid Character.

Now, I know the threshhold for Low-Int speech options is generally 3 or lower. What I'm curious about is if I set my Int to 4, (which, among other things, unlocks the Educated and Comprehension perks -  quite nice), and then wander around perpetually under the influence of Alcohol (reaping the +1 Str and -1 Int bonus/penalty at all times), giving me an effective Int of 3, will I see these low-int options? Or are the checks tied to *base* Intelligence, in much the same way that the checks for Perception based perks can be ruined by the '4 Eyes' trait?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would expect so. All speech challenges are affected (positively or negatively) by items that change your current stats, like alcohol, chems, magazines or clothing.

Additionaly, every perk check is done considering your base stats. In the case of the trait Four Eyes, it gives you a base penalty of -1 PER (giving a current bonus of +2 PER if you wear glasses), so that's the problem there.

Comment: Seeing as I just informed Eddie that I've taken care of his 'Bunny Hunter' problem, it looks like this is correct. Being drunk all the time does provide access to low-int dialog! Yay!